# ¿Como crear un TRIGGER en MySQL que me actualice el Stock despues de insertar la entrada de un producto?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Deseo crear un TRIGGER que me actualice el stock después de registrar la entrada del producto, la unica tabla que utilizo para hacer eso es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(El Stock que aparece en la tabla lo hice manual)

Al insertar la entrada de un producto, se llenan los todos los datos menos la fechaSalida y la cant_sal y claramente el stock ya que se debe de actualizar solo.

Lo intente hacer de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ingresar el dato me bota el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi que necesito ayuda para hacer ese Trigger, ya que teniendo el de actualizar el stock cuando ingrese productos puedo hacer el que los descuente, gracias

Comment: Como concepto... el stock quizá deba pertenecer a la tabla de producto. O pertenece a ella, o es un resultado de hacer un recorrido viendo los movimientos (o `inventario` en tu caso). Porque imagínate que de repente se registra un movimiento de hace 2 días en un producto, cuando ya tienes una serie de movimientos posteriores (entradas, salidas, regularizaciones...) ¿Tienes que actualizar entonces `stock` en todos los registros posteriores a ese nuevo? Además, personalmente pensaría si utilizar columnas difrentes para `FechaEntrada` y `FechaSalida` (lo mismo con cantidad) teniendo `motivo`

Answer (score 0):

El error señala que estas intentado actualizar un registro que estas ingresando, quizas solo tienes un error de logica, si no tienes un cambio en la base que no influya a la tabla que quieres modicar no puedes implementar un trigger, osea:

ingresar producto - trigger - modificar inventario
modificar producto - trigger - modificar inventario

lo que puedes hacer es por codigo ya sea js o php u otro modificar la tabla inventario

Answer (score -1):

MySQL, a diferencia de otros DBMS como Oracle **no admite trigguers que ejecuten operaciones DML sobre la misma tabla del TRIGGER**.
Eso significa que NO puedes hacer lo que quieres.

Lo que te conviene hacer es manejar stock y entrada de compras en dos tablas diferentes.